# Button not displaying React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi I am going through a React-Native tutorial and I used the TouchableHighLight to create a button. The first button displays properly and the second button displays a straight line with the text "Location".

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    View,
    TouchableHighlight,
    ActivityIndicator,
    Image
} from 'react-native';


class SearchPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.description}>
                Search for houses to buy!
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.description}>
                Search by place-name, postcode or search near your location.
                </Text>
            <View style={styles.flowRight}>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.searchInput}
                placeholder='Search via name or postcode'/>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Go</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Location</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <Image source={require('./Resources/house.png')} style={styles.image}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    description: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        fontSize: 18,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: "#656565"
    },
    container: {
        padding: 30,
        marginTop: 65,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    flowRight: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'stretch'
    },
    buttonText: {
        fontSize: 18,
        color: 'white',
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
    button: {
        height: 36,
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#48BBEC',
        borderColor: '#48BBEC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 8,
        marginBottom: 10,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    searchInput: {
        height: 36,
        padding: 4,
        marginRight: 5,
        flex: 4,
        fontSize: 18,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#48BBEC',
        borderRadius: 8,
        color: '#48BBEC'
    },
    image: {
    width: 217,
    height: 138
}
});

module.exports = SearchPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to import Button. To use a component you must import that component before you use it.

```
import {
  //...
  //...
  View,
  Button
  //...
} from 'react-native';
```

Just put Button inside your import statement and I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine.
[Android Emulator, Android 6.0, API 23, Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc9jQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is it copy/paste that causes the typo, there are two missing `<View>` tags in your code.

```
<View style={styles.container}>

  ...

  <View> // Missing tag for second button
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
      ...
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>

</View> // Missing tag for <View style={styles.container}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't spent much time to dig in and find the root cause but here is the quick fix. Remove `flex:1` from styles.button block and update your render function with following.

```
class SearchPage extends Component {
render() {
        let flextStyles = {
            flex: 1
        };
        //rest of the code as it is
        ...
        //replace go button with following code
        <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.button, flextStyles]}
                    underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Go</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        ...
       //rest of the code as it is
}}
```

Check screenshot, It will fix the problem.

[image]